# Leading 0 getting (stripped) converted to numeric from pandas json_normalize

Tags: python, pandas, json-normalize

From pandas **json_normalize**, json that contains `-03456`  converts it to `-3456`, but I want the data as it is (as a string).
Is there a way to get all data as string like we do in `pd.read_csv('foo.csv', dtype=str)`

Comment: `-03456` in json is an int, not a string. for this to be a valid string, it must be `"-03456"`. you can convert to a zero-padded string after reading with [`pd.Series.str.zfill`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.zfill.html)

Comment: I can't use zfill as it would pad other values, essentially I'm looking for a way to read everything as it is.

Comment: you could use the builtin [`json`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.load) python library and provide a dummy parse int which returns a string, e.g. `json.loads(mystring, parse_int=lambda x: x)`